How many 'A' and 'B' would be printed when using fork
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    if (fork() + fork() || fork() > 0) {
        printf("A\n");
        fork();
    }
    
    printf("B\n");
}

I understand the process ID returned for forking for a child process is 0 and for the parent, it returns the process ID of the newly created child process.
What I am confused by is the "fork() + fork()" in the if statement. Let's say we begin with one parent process P1 and the left fork in "fork() + fork()" would create a child process C1 for P1 but I am not sure if the right fork in "fork() + fork()" would cause both P1 and C1 to create a child process each.
Would appreciate if some one could walkthrough this problem step by step.

Looks like an ill-concieved homework or puzzle to me. Not a real programming problem.

Use pen and paper to draw the process tree generated. Then it's a simple counting exercise.

And don't forget the short-circuit evaluation of the || operator.

All processes execute same code, but have different fork results. Some do f1+f2 "A" f4 "B", some do f1+f2 f3 "A" f4 "B" and some do f1+f2 f3 "B". We have as many "B"s as there are processes, but processes with same past before "A" print a single one "A".  Then It only remains to list all the cases.

@n.m.couldbeanAI There's Contrived homework questions - Meta Stack Overflow . I think possible answers to this question can helps the asker as well as any potential future reader learn from it, so it should be fine for the site.

fork() + fork() calls fork twice. Each fork duplicates the process it is in. The C standard does not specify sequencing for the left and right operands of +; they may be evaluated in either order, but it will not matter in this program.
Either 8 or 4 “A” characters will be printed, depending on whether standard output is fully buffered or is line buffered or unbuffered, and 9 “B” characters will be printed. This is explained below.
Since both fork calls in fork() + fork() are executed, the result of this will be 4 processes. Of these, one will be the child of a child that received 0 for both fork calls. The three others will receive non-zero values with a non-zero sum except that the parent of the parent could receive to PID values that happen to sum to zero.1
Assuming that zero sum does not occur, 1 process has zero for the left side of the || and 3 have non-zero. The right side of || is evaluated only if the left side is zero, so 1 process evaluates fork() > 0 and 3 go directly into the body of the if. Evaluating fork() > 0 creates an additional process. Of these two, the parent receives 0 for the fork and does not enter the if body. Assuming the child receives a positive value for the fork1, it does enter the if body.
So 4 processes enter the if body and 1 does not. The 1 that does not prints “B” and is done.
Each of the 4 that enters the if body executes  printf("A\n");. If the standard output stream is unbuffered or line-buffered, as is typical when writing to a terminal, these print “A” immediately. So “A” is printed 4 times. Then each of these processes calls fork again, and then 8 processes proceed to printf("B\n");, so “B” is printed 8 more times, making 9.
If the standard output stream is fully buffered, as is typical when it is directed to a file, printf("A\n"); only writes “A” to a buffer. When each of these processes executes the following fork, this buffer is duplicated along with the entire process, so we have 8 processes with “A” pending in a buffer. Each of these processes proceeds to printf("B\n");, which adds “B” to the buffer. When the processes reach the end of main, program termination routines are executed, and those flush the buffers, printing the buffered text, so the 8 pending “A” characters and 8 pending “B” characters are printed, resulting in a total of 8 “A” characters and 9 “B” characters.
Footnote
1 pid_t is specified to be a signed type. I suspect this is so that fork and possibly other calls can return −1, and that valid process IDs are positive values, with negative values used only for error indications. However, I do not have documentation to that effect immediately at hand.

As a result of pid_t being a signed integer, it is impossible for fork() + fork() to ever equal zero. As a PID can never be negative, there are no two valid user space PID values for pid_t (ie. >=2) that when summed could equal zero. Closest you could get would be to cause an overflow to get a value of  -2.

@Dunes: Re “As a PID can never be negative”: As my footnote says, I do not have a source for that assertion. Also, while positive values would not cancel to zero in mathematical summation, they can overflow, for which the behavior is not defined by the C standard.

@EricPostpischil When you say "both fork calls in fork() + fork() are executed, the result of this will be 4 processes", so the main process will call fork() first to create a new child process and then the main process and the newly created child process would create another child process each? Am I understanding you correctly?

@User95797654974: Yes.

@EricPostpischil "except that the parent of the parent could receive to PID values that happen to sum to zero." I do not get this statement, not sure which process youre referring to when you say parent of the parent.

@User95797654974: When the first fork is executed in fork() + fork(), the parent will receive a non-zero value for it. When that parent executes the second fork, it will receive another non-zero value. So we have two numbers, a and b. It is possible that a + b produces zero, if, for example, a is +3 and b is −3. I do not think negative numbers are used for PIDs, but I do not have documentation saying that…

… Another possibility is that a and b are large numbers, say, 2,147,482 and 2,147,483, so that adding them overflows. When signed arithmetic overflows, the C standard does not define what the behavior of the program is. I do not expect these considerations were an intentional part of the exercise. The student is likely expected to figure that, except in the child of the child, fork() + fork() produces a non-zero value and program execution continues normally. (In the child of the child, both fork calls return zero, and the sum is zero.)

So basically when the first fork is executed by the main process, P1, it creates child process C1. P1 then executes second fork to get C2. Thus C1 and C2 produces a sum of zero if I understand u correctly? Because I thought when C1 executes second fork, another child process C3 is created and C1 becomes a parent thus the sum will not be zero I presume?

@EricPostpischil As you have noted, a negative value for pid_t has a special meaning. In waitpid(pid_t, ...), all negative values for pid_t have a special meaning. -1 means wait for any child. Any other negative number means wait for any child with process group ID equal to abs(pid_t).
